# Simplify the tensor product of two exponentials

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

If I have a 2-qubits circuit with a Ry rotation gate acting on each one :

[image]

My unitary transformation performed on the 2-qubits state is written as :

$$e^{-i\theta_{1} \sigma_{y}} \otimes e^{-i\theta_{2} \sigma_{y}}$$

I was wondering if I could simplify this product in order to have only one exponential(thus making the tensor product disappear) and what would the result be ?

Comment: Since the transformation is unitary, this is possible- any unitary can be written as exp(iH) with H an Hermitian operator.

Comment: Can you detail how you would do it ? I am still confused about those kind of calculations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two gates act on separate qubits, so their generators commute and you can use the identity
$$
e^A \otimes e^B = e^{A \otimes \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{I} \otimes B}
$$
to get
$$
e^{-i\theta_1 \sigma_y} \otimes e^{-i\theta_2 \sigma_y} = e^{-i(\theta_1 \sigma_y \otimes \mathbb{I} + \mathbb{I} \otimes \theta_2 \sigma_y)}
$$
if that helps simplify things.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer ! Beginner question : what are the generators of my gates here ?

Comment: The generator is the operator in the exponent; in your case, the generator of $R_y(\theta)$ is $-\theta \sigma_y$.

Comment: Do I have to also take the "i" or is it useless ?

Comment: Oops, nice catch; I've added the $i$ to the answer! The $i$ is not considered part of the generator though.